# Vue JS how to access data variable in script

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to vue.js.
and i am using 2.5.13 version.

I'm trying to access my `data` variable in component file script.
But this give to me a `undefined` message.

Id attribute in the component returns correct value, but inside script, it would return `undefined`.

If I want to use that variable, what do I need to do?

Below is my `app.js` code

```
import App from './components/App.vue';
new Vue(Vue.util.extend({
        router,
        data : {
            test : 1
        },
    }, App))
        .$mount('#root');
```

And bleow is my App component code

```
<template>
    <div id="app" :data-id="test">

    </div>
</template>
<script>
    console.log(this.data);
</script>
```

Comment: The code looks strange for me not sure where to start. I suggest you to learn basic VueJS from this free course https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step. An hour of taking this course would give you enough idea to start with VueJS in the proper manner. :)

Comment: thanks ! spicydog ^^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

assign variable `var app = new Vue({..})` to your Vue App. and access variable outside vue app by using `appname.variable_name` like `app.message`

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})


console.log(app.message);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>


<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
</div>
```

Comment: but what about the reactivity of Vue JS?